# Опция --check-links в bsdtar

Tags: tar

Всем привет. Прочитал страницу руководства по bsdtar. Разобрался во всем, кроме опции --check-links. Буду очень благодарен, если Вы мне объясните в каких случаях она необходима. Если не затруднит, то с примером использования пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Я уже задавал этот вопрос на РутКод, но, как мне кажется, данный вопрос имеет право быть и здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простым английским языком написано в **man**

```
--check-links
    warn if number of hard links to the file on the filesystem mismatch the number of links recorded in the archive
```

Это означает, что у файла, кроме имен  в этом tar в данной файловой системе есть и другие имена.

Дело в том, что в *nix у набора данных (файла, оглавления и т.п.) может быть много истинных имен (все равноправные). Их называют hard links. Такое ***новое*** имя можно добавить командой **ln**. Отличить их от первого имени (полученного в результате системного вызова open(), mkdir() и т.п.) нельзя.

Кроме них, именовать файл можно ссылкой (soft link). Ссылки создают командой ln с ключом **-s**.

Comment: @avp, в man pages FreeBSD написано так: Issue a warning message unless all links to each file are archived. Это я перевел, но, если не затруднит - приведите пожалуйста пример реального использования.

Comment: Про ссылки я тоже в курсе, но, у меня совсем нет опыта, поэтому я и интересуюсь примером реального использования этой функции.

Comment: Ни разу не использовал. 

Предполагаю, что если Вы хотите сделать архив, в котором максимально точно должно быть запомнено дерево файлов, то данная опция предупредит Вас, что при восстановлении не все пути к затареным файлам будут восстановлены.

Comment: Все равно спасибо.